# Access VBA: How to simulate row addition by the user

Tags: ms-access, row, ms-access-2010, addition, simulation

I have a form in datasheet view. I want vba to simulate the same steps as if the user added a new register (row) to the form. The steps that the user takes to add a new register are:

1. Click on a field of the last (empty) row (the row that has an asterisk on the left).
2. Type some characters. Important: This step converts the left asterisk into a pen, and a new row appears (with an asterisk) just under the row being edited.
3. Click on other row to save the new row.

I have tried to translate those steps into vba:

1.

```
    If Not my_form.NewRecord Then
        RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
    End If
```

2.

```
    my_form.field_1 = value_1
    my_form.field_2 = value_2
    ...
```

3.

```
    my_form.Requery
```

And the result is:

1. Last (new) row is selected. That is ok.
2. Values are added to the fields, but the asterisk isn't converted into a pen, and a new line (with an asterisk) is NOT added. Bad!
3. The rows are reordered, so the new row (the row with values just entered) is not shown as the last row. Bad!

I want the new row (with values) to be shown as the last one (just before the empty line that has an asterisk), as if the user had entered the values. In other words, I want to simulate completely the addition of a new row by the user.

---

**Update**: I discovered the cause: If we assign a value to a checkbox first (before assigning values to textboxes), then the new row doesn't appear:

```
If Not my_form.NewRecord Then           ' go to new (empty) row (if not already on it)
    RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
End If

my_form.my_checkbox.Value = 1           ' if we first assign a value to a checkbox, then no new row appears under our row
my_form.my_textbox_1 = "aa"             ' no new row appears
my_form.my_textbox_2 = "bb"             ' no new row appears
...
```

But, if we assign a value to a textbox first, then a new row appears:

```
If Not my_form.NewRecord Then           ' go to new (empty) row (if not already on it)
    RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
End If

my_form.my_textbox_1 = "aa"             ' if we first assign a value to a textbox, then a new row appears under our row
my_form.my_checkbox.Value = 1    
my_form.my_textbox_2 = "bb"
...
```

Incredible, but true.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in MS-Access - I ran across the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

What version of MS Access are you using? That looks quite old. This works for me:

```
Dim frm As Form
Set frm = Forms!aForm

DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
frm.aControl = ""
```

Of course, it depends on where you are running the code, if it is in the form itself, `Me` would be fine.

Comment: I'm using Access 2010 (you can see it in the labels). As I have commented in the update, the cause was that I was setting a checkbox before setting textboxes.